# Spring simplejdbc Stored procedure using resultset Extractor

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, stored-procedures, spring-data, spring-jdbc

I am new to Spring and i'm learning it now. Meanwhile i am stuck at a particular place . i am able to execute the stored procedure but its not returning me any result back .please guide me .I'm using sybase database . The stored procedure contains two parameters one is for the input and the other is the output.

```
  public String getGetNextIdQuery(String string, String region){
      String custId = ""; 
      JdbcTemplate jtempl  = jdbcTemplateMap.get(region);

  Map<String, Object> inParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  String nextId = "?";

           inParams.put("len", string);
           inParams.put("acct_id",nextId);

           SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jtempl).
            withProcedureName("pr_acct_id")
            .withReturnValue()
            .withReturnValue().withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess()
            .declareParameters(new SqlOutParameter("RETURN", java.sql.Types.VARCHAR))
            .declareParameters(new SqlParameter("len", java.sql.Types.SMALLINT))
            .declareParameters(new SqlParameter("acct_id", java.sql.Types.VARCHAR))
          .declareParameters(new SqlReturnResultSet("RESULT", new ResultSetExtractor<String>() {

              @Override
              public String extractData(
                            ResultSet arg0)
                                          throws SQLException {
                    String custId = "";
                    int i = 0;                  
                    while(arg0.next()) {  
                       System.out.println(i++);
                       custId = arg0.getString("acct_id");
                     }

              return custId;

              }

        }));                       
           Map<String, Object> result = simpleJdbcCall.execute(inParams);

            System.out.println((String)result.get("RESULT"));

            custId = (String)result.get("RESULT");

         return custId;

            }
```

Comment: If the procedure only has 2 parameters, why are you defining 4 params?

Comment: M.Deinum  CREATE PROCEDURE pr_acct_id len @smallint, acct_id CHAR(6) OUTPUT AS   this is the stored proc declaration

Comment: And that adds what? Again you are creating 4 parameters in your java code .

Comment: No i could debug and see that only two parameters are passed